# How to use multiple search controller in same view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, autocomplete, google-places-api

In my application, I want to use multiple(two) Search controller for GooglePlace autocomplete already I implemented one search controller it works fine but now I don't know how to implement another search controller in same view controller please give some knowledge to implement that.

Here I give the code I implemented the single search controller.

```
var resultsViewController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController?
var pickUpSearchController: UISearchController?
var dropSearchController: UISearchController?

let pickUpSearchBarBackView = UIView()
let dropSearchBarBackView = UIView()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    pickUpSearchBarFunction()

}
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    var pickUpSearchBarFrame = pickUpSearchController?.searchBar.frame
    pickUpSearchBarFrame?.size.width = (pickUpSearchController?.searchBar.frame.size.width)!
    pickUpSearchController?.searchBar.frame = pickUpSearchBarFrame!
}
func pickUpSearchBarFunction() {
    resultsViewController = GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController()
    resultsViewController?.delegate = self
    pickUpSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsViewController)
    pickUpSearchController?.searchResultsUpdater = resultsViewController

    if UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width == 320 {
        pickUpSearchBarBackView.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 75.0, width: 300.0, height: 50.0)
    }
    else if(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width == 375)
    {
        pickUpSearchBarBackView.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 75.0, width: 355.0, height: 60.0)
    }
    else if(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width == 414)
    {
        pickUpSearchBarBackView.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 75.0, width: 394.0, height: 60.0)
    }

    pickUpSearchBarBackView.addSubview((pickUpSearchController?.searchBar)!)
    //(pickUpSearchController?.searchBar)!.center = self.pickUpSearchBarBackView.center
    view.addSubview(pickUpSearchBarBackView)
    pickUpSearchController?.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    pickUpSearchController?.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
    pickUpSearchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    definesPresentationContext = true

    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    pickUpSearchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = .top
}


extension HomeViewController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewControllerDelegate {
func resultsController(_ resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController,
                       didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {

    pickUpSearchController?.isActive = false
    //strForLat = "\(place.coordinate.latitude)"
    //strForLong = "\(place.coordinate.longitude)"

    let coordinateSearch: CLLocationCoordinate2D? = place.coordinate
    print(coordinateSearch!.latitude)
    print(coordinateSearch!.longitude)
    strForLat = "\(coordinateSearch!.latitude)"
    strForLong = "\(coordinateSearch!.longitude)"

    globalCamera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: Double(strForLat)!, longitude: Double(strForLong)!, zoom: zoomLevel)
    self.googleMapsView.camera = globalCamera
    //let marker = GMSMarker()
    customerMarker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(Double(strForLat)!, Double(strForLong)!)
    customerMarker.title = place.name
    customerMarker.snippet = place.formattedAddress
    customerMarker.map = self.googleMapsView
    //globalMarker.icon = GMSMarker.markerImage(with: UIColor.blue)
    customerMarker.tracksViewChanges = true
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) // dismiss after select place
    pickUpSearchController?.searchBar.text = place.formattedAddress

    print("Place name: \(place.name)")
    print("Place address: \(place.formattedAddress!)")
    print("Place attributions: \(place.attributions)")

    //getLatLngForaddress(addressStr: (searchController?.searchBar.text)!)
    getLatandLngForPickUpaddress()
}

func resultsController(_ resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController,
                       didFailAutocompleteWithError error: Error){
    print("Error: ", error.localizedDescription)
}

// Turn the network activity indicator on and off again.
func didRequestAutocompletePredictions(forResultsController resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController) {
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
}

func didUpdateAutocompletePredictions(forResultsController resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController) {
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
}
func wasCancelled(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) // when cancel search
}
```

}

Comment: don't use GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController, use the option for customizing the incoming datasource and making your own controller, then use either two collectionviews and if/then statements to differentiate between which collection or table view is being accessed for load a dictionary with two contollers and add them as container views to the main view controller

Answer (score 1):

You can handle it by comparing the resultsController to your searchResultsController specific to UISearchController.

```
extension ViewController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewControllerDelegate {
func resultsController(_ resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController,
                       didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {

    if resultsController == sourceResultsViewController {

        // Do something with the selected place.

    } else if resultsController == destinationResultsViewController {

        // Do something with the selected place.

    }
```